# Best place for get email when user use openid login

Tags: java, spring, authentication, openid, spring-security

I'm developing some site with openid auth.

For openid auth I use standarts spring security filter and provider: 
org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter,
org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationProvider

And for create user I use my custom UserDetailsService.

So question is where's the best place (filter, provider, detailsService) to save user email got from OpenIDAttribute?

Answer (score 0):

Typically its the UserDetailsService where you construct your domain objects i.e. load/generate a "User" object based on the information passed from OpenId/SAML etc. I guess you're trying to implement some sort of on the fly provisioning in which a user signs in with his OpenId credentials and you look for an existing local account and if you cant find one you generate one?

Comment: Hi Toby, this would be the case for me. How do you get the username or email once the user has logged in via OpenId?